# executeAsyncScript method doesn't appear when driver is instantiated as "Webdriver driver"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Going through the Webdriver Timeouts I noticed that for setScriptTimeout, if I type

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I cannot see the method to select for "executeAsyncScript" when I type "driver." (driver dot)

But if I type:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I can see the method for "executeAsyncScript" and so I can type

```
driver.executeAsyncScript("", args);
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [in the Javadoc](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/), the method `executeAsyncScript` is inherited from the class `RemoteWebDriver`, while the interface `WebDriver` has no such method.

Because you declare your variable as a `WebDriver` object you cannot call its subclass methods.